# Highcharts: how to best support data with more than 2 y-axes

Tags: highcharts

I have a scenario where the user can pick up to 5 different data sets to be included at one time. These data sets have vastly different scales (one might be from 0-100 while another could be 500-6000, and so on). These data sets are sensor readings (temperature, PH, etc.).

They all share a common x-axis in that each data set has different points across time, which is the x-axis. In addition to this, I want to correlate all of these different data sets with another data set that is basically a set of activities that happened at certain points in time, so I want to be able to say "for each event, what were the different sensor readings at that time" in a nice, graphical way.

What would be the best type of graph in highcharts to be able to display these? Obviously, a regular line graph doesn't work because of the different scales. A dual axis chart isn't enough. I've been playing around with a bunch of different stuff, but I haven't found anything that looks good.

Comment: Highcharts has a demo for this case: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Comment: Ah man, I feel stupid now! I was looking through the demos for 2 hours yesterday and couldn't find that. I must be blind :)